# Sum up value of span elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bigger calculator, which simplified would be something like this:

```
$('input').keyup(function () { // run anytime the value changes
var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()) || 0; // get value of field
var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val()) || 0;

$('#sum1').html(firstValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
$('#sum2').html(secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it

});
```

How can I take the values of sum1 and sum2, and add them to a Sum?

They are spans which get populated after Input have been populated.
Thank you

Comment: there is no sum field

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/168zb1ez/2/ ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"How can I take the values of sum1 and sum2, and add them to a Sum?".

Well...

```
var sum1 = parseFloat($('#sum1').text());
var sum2 = parseFloat($('#sum2').text());

$('#sum3').html(sum1 + sum2);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/168zb1ez/3/

Comment: *"Is that what you want?"* - is not an answer. first of all you should understand what the OP wants in order to answer it. You seems to have enough rep to post comments asking for clarification.

Comment: I replied the question based on what he asked. "How can I take the values of sum1 and sum2, and add them to a Sum?" Is that what i answered. After see 2 comments that wasn't replied, i thought that he left from the website, as many newbies of the Stack Overflow do every (ask and left). But i'll remove the "clarification" words.

Comment: This newbie is a she ;) Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted, I have never seen JS code so this might have been a dumb question, but your help was more than needed. Have an awesome Sunday!

Comment: Great! I hope you have a awesome day too :)